# phpMyAdmin won't keep some of the tables for config storage

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I log in to my local phpMyAdmin install I continually get this error:

```
  The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why. 
  Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.
```

I have clicked the link to add the tables every time and still get the error. Can anyone shed some light on this?

[image: Screen Shot]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zeroconf mechanism you are using do not work for all scenarios. The covered scenarios are explained at http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#zero-configuration but if you have multiple databases, you should probably do a manual configuration as explained at http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manual-configuration.

Comment: I've never had to do anything special in the past, this only started on the last upgrade.

Comment: Which tables are reported as missing?

Comment: I didn't see it report certain tables missing.

Comment: Even when you click on "Find out why" ?

Comment: Sorry, it does list the missing tables, however, they aren't missing. See the added image above.

Comment: just checked my config file, the tables that were missing weren't missing from the DB as reported, but missing from the config.

Comment: Thanks @indymx, this misleading message will be tracked at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11804.